# Converting a complicated date function to

Tags: excel, pervasive-sql

I am trying to convert a series of date functions from excel into a single Actian-PSQL function.

The excel is as follows;

```
A1=Today()
B1=DATE(YEAR($A$1),MONTH($A$1),DAY($A$1) + 2-WEEKDAY($A$1)) [This Monday]
B2=DATE(YEAR($A$1),MONTH($A$1),DAY($A$1) +9-WEEKDAY($A$1)) [Next Monday]
B3=IF(A1>B1,B2,B1)
```

The goal of these functions is to determine the date of the next coming Monday, and query the database for all items with that date. I currently plan on using 5 iterations of this query for each day of the week.

Comment: What if today is a Monday? Do you want today's date or the next week's Monday?

Comment: It is only where today()>Monday that I want to see the data from next monday's date. If today()=Monday then pull the information from today.